# Look up value in data frame stored over multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, lookup

I am trying to calculate the average amount of money actors are generating for movies. In my dataset this is defined by `gross` as shown in a snippet below:

```
movie_title  actor_1_name     actor_2_name     actor_3_name  ...  gross
x            Christoph Waltz  Johnny Depp      Emma Stone    x    309404152
x            Mark Addy        Christopher Lee  Naomi Watts   x    73058679 
x            Will Smith       Tom Hanks        *NA*          x    179020854
x            Tony Curran      Jeremy Renner    Matt Damon    x    93417865
x            Chris Evans      Eva Green        *NA*          x    85313679
..etc
```

First thing I did was transform the three `actor_X_name` columns into one single column of unique actor names with the following line:

```
actors <- unique(data.frame(actor_name = c(df[,"actor_1_name"], df[,"actor_2_name"], df[,"actor_3_name"])))
```

The above returns a new data frame with a single column of unique actor names from the original dataset.

How can I best interate through these ~4900 observations, looking up the value in the original data frame across `actor_X_name`'s (3 conditions)? The goal being to fetch the `gross` of the matching row so I can calculate on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your input:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~title, ~actor_1_name, ~actor_2_name, ~actor_3_name, ~gross,
                      "A", "Christoph Waltz",  "Johnny Depp",      "Emma Stone",    309404152,
                      "B", "Mark Addy",        "Christopher Lee",  "Naomi Watts",   73058679 ,
                      "C", "Will Smith",       "Tom Hanks",        NA,            179020854,
                      "D", "Tony Curran",      "Jeremy Renner",    "Matt Damon",    93417865,
                      "E", "Chris Evans",      "Eva Green",        NA,           85313679)
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   title actor_1_name    actor_2_name    actor_3_name     gross
#>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 A     Christoph Waltz Johnny Depp     Emma Stone   309404152
#> 2 B     Mark Addy       Christopher Lee Naomi Watts   73058679
#> 3 C     Will Smith      Tom Hanks       NA           179020854
#> 4 D     Tony Curran     Jeremy Renner   Matt Damon    93417865
#> 5 E     Chris Evans     Eva Green       NA            85313679
```

You can achieve your goal with one single `tidyr` function: `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(matches("actor_\\d_name"))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    title     gross name         value          
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          
#>  1 A     309404152 actor_1_name Christoph Waltz
#>  2 A     309404152 actor_2_name Johnny Depp    
#>  3 A     309404152 actor_3_name Emma Stone     
#>  4 B      73058679 actor_1_name Mark Addy      
#>  5 B      73058679 actor_2_name Christopher Lee
#>  6 B      73058679 actor_3_name Naomi Watts    
#>  7 C     179020854 actor_1_name Will Smith     
#>  8 C     179020854 actor_2_name Tom Hanks      
#>  9 C     179020854 actor_3_name NA             
#> 10 D      93417865 actor_1_name Tony Curran    
#> 11 D      93417865 actor_2_name Jeremy Renner  
#> 12 D      93417865 actor_3_name Matt Damon     
#> 13 E      85313679 actor_1_name Chris Evans    
#> 14 E      85313679 actor_2_name Eva Green      
#> 15 E      85313679 actor_3_name NA
```

With `matches` you're selecting all columns written in that way.

The action you perform with `pivot_longer` is to reshape your data so that the columns selected by `matches` become one and the content of the other columns is repeated for each row.

`title` and `gross` will work as unique identifier of each row.

---

If you need to calculate the mean gross for each actor, you can use:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 pivot_longer(matches("actor_\\d_name"), values_to = "actor_name") %>% 
 filter(!is.na(actor_name)) %>% 
 group_by(actor_name) %>% 
 summarise(mean_gross = mean(gross), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 14 x 2
#>    actor_name      mean_gross
#>    <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1 Chris Evans      85313679 
#>  2 Christoph Waltz 309404152 
#>  3 Christopher Lee  73058679 
#>  4 Emma Stone      309404152 
#>  5 Eva Green        85313679 
#>  6 Jeremy Renner    93417865 
#>  7 Johnny Depp     309404152 
#>  8 Mark Addy        73058679 
#>  9 Matt Damon       93417865 
#> 10 Naomi Watts      73058679 
#> 11 Tom Hanks       179020854 
#> 12 Tony Curran      93417865 
#> 13 Will Smith      179020854
```

Note that I `filter`ed out the NAs, because they have no meaning.
Also in `pivot_longer` I defined that name of the new column I created, so to be more readable and consistent with your intents.

Comment: `# with average

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("actor")) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(gross))`